# SQLServerException: The connection is closed caused by databricks activity in Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, databricks

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline which launches 4 Databricks activities in parallel.

The 4 activities do almost the same thing:
Write different data in 4 different SQL Server tables in the same database

```
   val df= spark.sql("SELECT * FROM TAB1")
   df
      .write
      .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")
      .mode("overwrite")
      .option("truncate", value = true)
      .option("reliabilityLevel", "BEST_EFFORT")
      .option("tableLock", "false")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("dbtable", "dbo.TAB1")
      .option("user", u)
      .option("password", p)
      .option("schemaCheckEnabled", "false")
      .option("batchsize", "1048576")
      .save()
```

We noticed that although the job executes successfully, sometimes it fails with an:

`SQLServerException: The connection is closed error`.

The data we try to write in SQL takes between 10 and 20 minutes to finish entirely.

I am thinking maybe the fact that we execute the 4 jobs in parallel is the source of the problem, but I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mention that you are running 4 Databricks activities in parallel, in those activities you are writing data to 4 different tables in the same database and the error occurs only sometimes - so there are **high chances that you are facing the capacity issue on SQL Server side.**

If you are using Azure SQL Database, you can **upgrade the tier** and this should work fine.

Also, make sure the **Azure Integration Runtime has sufficient Cores and Memory to run your 4 pipelines in parallel**. If data is huge it might be possible that IR is incapable to process it. **Create a new IR and use it to run your pipelines.** Refer below image.

[image]

Alternatively, you can **run your pipeline in serial instead of parallel**, this will leave the database and IR with enough memory to deal with the data.